# How to test Angular 2 headers being sent by service using Http module?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

When testing an Angular 2 service that makes http GET, POST, PUT, etc. requests, is there a way to test and verify the headers that are being sent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! If you use the Angular2 MockBackend module inside your unit tests, you can subscribe to connections and check your headers inside there. For example:

```js
var mockBackend = TestBed.get(MockBackend); 
mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqu‌al('application/json‌​');         

      let options = new ResponseOptions({
         body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'returned' })
      });
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
 });
```

Comment: Also you should mention that to get it they need to use var mockBackend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

Comment: Also i think to get check headers better way would be  expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/json');